# Equality of generic types

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm trying to compare 2 types.
I have `class Foo<Bar>` but i dont know the generic arguments
I have to know is it a `Foo` object or not.
The following code does not work, I dont know why.

```
foreach (var type in types.Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Foo<>))
{
    use(type);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
There is a method called `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` and I can compare my object with this methods return type now.